# I want to remove all charactors from string /integer from string in php

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I want to remove character and integer from a string.

Let's say it is string: `Tel.  040- 36 49 03 SEC`.
How I can remove all characters from above string?

I am using

```
$string='Tel.  040- 36 49 03 SEC';
$mobileString=trim(str_replace(range(0,9),'',$string));

$mobileNumber=trim(chop($string,$mobileString));
```

It's not working exactly as I need.

Comment: Your question is unclear - what exactly do you want `$mobileString` and `$mobileNumber` to look like?

Comment: `I want to remove character and integer from a string` - You won't have much remaining :)

Comment: You want to have the final output containing only the special characters?

Comment: `$string='';` - voila! **All** characters removed.

Comment: Maybe you want to remove everything except digits? `preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $string)`

Comment: @Ahmad: Careful, that would remove `+` signs too, which may be vital to the meaning of a phone number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$string='Tel. 040- 36 49 03 SEC';
echo preg_replace("/[A-Za-z]+/","",$string);
```

Do you want to remove `.` and `-` also ?

```
echo preg_replace("/[A-Za-z\-\. ]+/","",$string); // this will just give you number, removes all characters
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
$words = preg_replace('/[0-9\-]+/', '', $string);
```

Comment: @MianAnjum: What do you mean "also"? It does nearly the opposite of what Prasanth's regex does.

Comment: @TimPietzcker This is question I want to remove character and integer from a string that i does.